# how do i print to a printer 2 strings in java

Tags: java, printers

ill try make this as simple as possible

im trying to print a bill that contains this:

```
String text="Home\n";
       text+="Sweet\n"+"Home";
String cut_page="((char)12)m"; //this string is just a reference
```

i want to print to a printer the string "text" and immediately after print "cut_page".

i want to do it in this order because concatenating havent worked for me, because for some reason it cuts in the middle of the phrase.

---

bellow if the real method im using, if whats above is enough for you then ignore this part

```
String param = request.getParameter("empresa");
    System.out.println("empresa");
    System.out.println(param);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String corte="m";
    DetalleImpresion detalle = gson.fromJson(param, DetalleImpresion.class);
    System.out.println(detalle);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> detalles_factura = detalle.getDetalle_factura();

    String total = detalle.total;
    String direccion = detalle.direccion;
    String fecha = detalle.fecha;
    String facturacli = detalle.factura;
    String cliente = detalle.cliente;
    String empresa = detalle.empresa;
    String clienteNombre = detalle.cliente_nombre;
    String guia = detalle.guia_remision;

    String factura = empresa+"\t"+facturacli+"\n"+"\t"+fecha+"\n";
            factura+="\t"+clienteNombre+"\tRUC\n"+"\t"+direccion+"\n"+guia+"\n";//+"=======================================\n";

    for(int i=0; i< detalles_factura.size();i++){
        HashMap<String, Object> row = detalles_factura.get(i);      
        factura+=row.get("cantidad").toString() +"\t" + row.get("producto_nombre").toString()+
                "\t"+row.get("precio_unitario").toString()+"\t"+row.get("a_pagar").toString()+"\n";                 
    }   

    StringBuilder facfinal = new StringBuilder();
    facfinal.append(factura);
    facfinal.append(corte);
    String ff=facfinal.toString();
    //factura+=corte;

    String printerName = request.getParameter("dispositivo");
    System.out.println(printerName);
    AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
    attributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
    attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
    attributeSet.add(ColorSupported.NOT_SUPPORTED);
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, attributeSet);
    int indexOfEmpsonPrinter = -1;

    for( int i = 0 , count = services.length ;  i < count ; ++i ){
        System.out.println(services[i].getName());
        if( services[i].getName().equals(printerName) ){
            indexOfEmpsonPrinter = i;

        }

    }

    if(indexOfEmpsonPrinter!=-1){

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ff.getBytes("UTF8"));
        InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(factura.getBytes("UTF8"));
        PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(2));


        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
        Doc doc2 = new SimpleDoc(is2, flavor, null);
        DocPrintJob job = services[indexOfEmpsonPrinter].createPrintJob();

        try {
            job.print(doc, pras);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        is.close();
        is2.close();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Impresora no encontrada");
    }
```

Comment: Please show only the relevant part. The whole business logic you posted makes it harder to isolate the problem, and help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`DocFlavor` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.html):

> A Java Print Service instance is not required to support the following
>   print data formats and print data representation classes. In fact, a
>   developer using this class should never assume that a particular print
>   service supports the document types corresponding to these pre-defined
>   doc flavors.

Java is probably autosensing the "text/plain" doc flavor from your print job. Most printers that I have encountered have only rudimentary support for this.

In your case, I suspect the problem is that the printer wants a "\r\n" endline rather than Java's "\n". But more generally, you will have much better control over the results if you actually implement your own [`Printable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) object.